# change color of only ONE menu item icon in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, background-color, menuitem

i want to change only one menu item in the action bar. I tried to change the same icon color instead of making it transparent into the desired color but the edges show the background of the action bar.

Here is my action bar what it looks like:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1sjnk975dnj17kr/before.png?dl=0

And here is the goal i want to reach:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ul7hh2gxtfox1pk/goal.png?dl=0

Here are my xml files:

menu_main.xml

```
<item
    android:id= "@+id/location"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_room_white_48dp"
    android:title=""
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>


<item
    android:id= "@+id/report"
    android:icon="@drawable/report"
    android:title=""
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>


<item
    android:id= "@+id/message"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_comment_white_48dp"
    android:title=""
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#B9ACC1</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#827689</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">#827689</item>

    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">


    <item name="android:padding">15dip</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Post your xml please

Comment: just in case no one has a good answer you could subclass ActionBar in order to apply your custom styles. It's a long way yet not impossible

Comment: @Skizo check it out, Thanks!

Comment: @user2875404 how to do that? do you have useful links? Thanks!

Comment: This pretty much depends on how much adjustments the ActionBar class allows you. If the given methods aren't sufficient, you can subclass RelativeLayout and go from there. You can think of custom classes as little apps within your app. You write the layout/bahavior of the class just like you do the layout/behavior of your app (OOP, basically) http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-actionbar/ for example http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE1 :
Adding a way to avoid xml and code duplication.

UPDATE2 :
Adding static listener.

I don't know if you can achieve your goal just by changing your menu.xml but the Toolbar is a viewGroup so you can achieve your goal with a view.xml which should looks like it :

toolbar.xml :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="#000000">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_first"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_lock" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="#000000">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_second"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_lock" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

It can be boring to add this code on all of your xml so i advice you to to use thé `<include />` attribute like this :

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, you just have to set the Toolbar and use the Button

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button buttonFirst = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_first);
    final Button buttonSecond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_second);

    buttonFirst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    buttonSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
   });
}
```

If all of your button have the same listener, you can make them static into avoid the code duplication :

IconListener.java :

```
public class IconListener {

    public static View.OnClickListener listenerButtonOne = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //DO what you want
        }
    };

    public static View.OnClickListener listenerButtonTwo = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do what you want
        }
    };
}
```

So your MainActivity.java became

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button buttonFirst = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_first);
    final Button buttonSecond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_second);

    buttonFirst.setOnClickListener(IconListener.listenerButtonOne)
    buttonSecond.setOnClickListener(IconListener.listenerButtonTwo);
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked but it's not efficient if i have like 10 activity and each activity has different layout... correct me if i'm wrong!

Comment: I've just updated my response into show how to achieve it in an efficient way